# How to correctly use the map operator in this Java 8+ application in order to retrieve, modify and update an object on the DB?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

I am working on a Java 8+ project based on Spring Boot and I am finding some difficulties trying to use a "functional" approach to my code. I admit that I remained at Java 7 approach and I am trying to improve my code with modern construct.

I have this service class method:

```
/`
 * Deactivate an user retrieved by its user ID
 * @throws NotFoundException 
 */
@Override
public Optional<User> deactivateUser(int userId) throws NotFoundException {
    
    Optional<User> retrievedUser = this.userRepository.findById(userId);
    
    return Optional.ofNullable(retrievedUser)      
            .map((user) -> retrievedUser.get())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(String.format("The user having ID %s was not found", userId))));
}
```

As you can see it first retrieve an `Optional<User>` object using a Spring Data JPA repository.

Then I am trying to use functional approach (using `map()` operator) to implement the following behavior:

1. Retrieve the `User` object contained into the `Optional<User>` object retrieved using the repository.
2. If the retrieved `Optional<User>` object is not empty --> do some operation before return this object.
3. If the retrieved `Optional<User>` object is empty --> throw the `NotFoundException()` exception.

I think that point 1 and 3 are ok. The problem is that I am not understanding how to correctly put some logic into the `map()` function, at the moment I have something like this:

```
.map((user) -> retrievedUser.get())
```

What exactly means it? I think that it put the `User` object retrieved by the `retrievedUser.get()` into an `user` variable that is returned. Is it my reasoning correct? (I am absolutely not sure).

My problem is that before to return this `User` object I need to perform some operation (basically update a field named `isActive` setting it to `false` and then update it using the Spring Data JPA `save()` method). How can I do it? Can you show me an example? I think that for me could be enough an example where I have a multi line function into the `map()` operator (also a function that first perform the `retrievedUser.get()` operation and that print it into another line, then I should be able to perform the needed logic by myself).

Comment: I guess if you have an method in User Class e.g. performAction(User) you need to call this way only. 

return Optional.ofNullable(retrievedUser
            .map((user) -> performAction(user)))
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(String.format("The user having ID %s was not found", userId))));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [map method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) takes a Function object as a parameter. The Function is a generic interface that only has one method that acts like a callback, so in order to achieve your desired result, you have to implement this interface and pass it to the method. To do so, you can implement it by using a [lambda expression](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_lambda.asp) (which is the way you're trying to do). In this case, the function will be called passing the object found by your repository.

You probably want something like this:

```java
    return Optional.ofNullable(retrievedUser)
        .map((user) -> {
            // do your operation with the object
            return user;
        })
        .map(updatedUser -> userRepository.save(updatedUser))
        .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(String.format("The user having ID %s was not found", userId))));
```

Note that inside the lambda expression, you're dealing with the `User` and not with the `Optional<User>`, so there's no need to use `.get()` there.
You should also note that the `orElse`/`orElseThrow` kind of functions return an instance of the object and not the Optional, so you'll have to change the return type of your method.

[This article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional) is a pretty good read if want to understand what each operation does and how to use them.

Comment: Why you concatenate a second map() operator in order to perform the repository save() method? Can I perform this operation directly inside the body of my lambda? (my idea is to perform the User object manipulation and the call to the save() method directly into the lamba body avoiding to do a second map concatenation. But maybe I am missing something and exist some reason to keep it separate? Tnx

Comment: Yes, you could place all your operations inside of one `.map` but it is often easier to understand the code if you write it as a series of small concise operations. It is an optional stylistic advice to make things easier to maintain. You can find more tips on this article https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-lambda-expressions-tips

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function which accept an user and return an user for doing the logic of (2) . For example :

```java
public User processUser(User user) {
    user.setActive(false);
    return user;
}
```

and then refer to this function in the map operator :

```
return Optional.ofNullable(retrievedUser
            .map((user) -> processUser(user))
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(String.format("The user having ID %s was not found", userId))));
```

You can further use method reference to simplify it to:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(retrievedUser
            .map(this::processUser)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(String.format("The user having ID %s was not found", userId))));
```